# Select from drop-down menu

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

On [website](https://fs2.formsite.com/meherpavan/form2/index.html?1537702596407) there is a drop-down menu `"Best Time to Contact"` and I click on it but I can't choose from the d-d menu. Suggestions?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\ChromeDriverExtracted\chromedriver")
driver.get("https://fs2.formsite.com/meherpavan/form2/index.html?1537702596407")

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("RESULT_RadioButton-9").click())
select.select_by_visible_text("Morning").click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the below code

```
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
select = Select(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "RESULT_RadioButton-9"))))
select.select_by_visible_text('Evening')
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

and it did the trick. This is with explicit waits, which is recommended in Selenium automation.

You should not use `.click()` here

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("RESULT_RadioButton-9").click())
```

Also, I tested your code without `.click()`, it works as well.

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("RESULT_RadioButton-9"))
select.select_by_visible_text("Morning")
```

Comment: You were very close, you had extra `.click()` with you.

Comment: Yea I know, but need to wait a couple of minutes. Then it will not be a problem :)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#RESULT_RadioButton-9 > option:nth-child(2)").click()
```